# delegate method for CMMotionManager

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-motion

I just want to know that when we call the method of startGyroUpdates with CMMotionManager and fix some updateInterval say to 1.0/60.0 , then is there any delegate method that we have to implement where we can get the gyro updates. If not then where/how we can get the gyro-updates.

Also if there is some useful code snippet to find out device change in position i-e if the device is moved up or down from some reference point.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says:

startGyroUpdates
Starts gyroscope updates without a handler.

```
- (void)startGyroUpdates
```

Discussion
**You can get the latest gyroscope data through the gyroData property**. You must call stopGyroUpdates when you no longer want your application to process gyroscope updates.

Availability
Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
See Also

```
– startGyroUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:
```

Declared In
CMMotionManager.h

Answer (score 0):

Adding to xs2bush's correct answer: See the documentation links in [Simple iPhone motion detect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214197/simple-iphone-motion-detect/5220796#5220796) for more information.

Regarding the second point moved from some reference point, definitely not. At the moment there is no way at all to determine displacement with an acceptable precision. There are several questions and discussions about this like 
[Getting displacement from accelerometer data with Core Motion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449565/getting-displacement-from-accelerometer-data-with-core-motion) or 
[Measuring time the vehicle takes to accelerate in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654864/measuring-time-the-vehicle-takes-to-accelerate-in-iphone) (I don't believe the 3% ;-)